# what is the meaning of (void*)&

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a piece of code saying

```
clock.start();
for (unordered_map <uint32_t,HostTraffic>::iterator internalIPItr = hostTraffic.begin();
     internalIPItr != hostTraffic.end();
     ++internalIPItr)
  {
     if (!pgBulkInserter.insert(NULL, internalIPItr -> first,
                                internalIPItr -> second.inboundFlows,
                                (void*)&(internalIPItr -> second.outboundPortIPs),
                                internalIPItr -> second.roles)) {
        return -1;
     }
     clock.incrementOperations();
  }
```

My problem is I don't understand the meaning of

```
(void*)&(internalIPItr -> second.outboundPortIPs).
```

You can consider `for(....)` as

```
for (int internalItr = beginning -> end)
```

where the type of `internalItr` is `unordered_map` and `internalItr->second` gives an instance of `HostTraffic`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pointer to the address of `internalIPItr->second.outboundPortIPs`, given by `&`, is converted to `void*`.

Comment: why do i need it or what is the advantage of it?

Comment: It's usually used when the function (in your case: pgBulkInserter.insert) requires a parameter, but the exact type of the parameter cannot be determined in advance. Example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686736(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Already answered is what it does (returns a `void*`)

But you should be forewarned this this type of casting is called [Type Punning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) and it's considered Undefined Behavior.  (Though, it works in all of the compilers I know with the appropriate compile options set or unset.)

Comment: More [type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) than type punning in this case. Doesn't make it any less dangerous, though.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a pointer to `internalIPItr->second.outboundPortIPs` to a function that takes `void*`.

The `&` takes the address of `internalIPItr->second.outboundPortIPs` (i.e. gives you a pointer to it).  `(void*)` casts that pointer to `void`.

Answer (score 1):

`internalPltr` is a pointer to a structure, wich has a member named `second` which has a member named `outboundPortIPs`. The `&` (addressof) operator returns its memory address, then `(void *)` casts (performs an explicit type conversion on) that address to a void pointer.

Comment: Um, but why is an explicit cast to `void*` required?